# How to make Encrypted Connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, server, serversocket

I am making a server in java using `ServerSocket` and `Socket` class. I wanted it encrypted so I used `RSA` encryption to encrypt and decrypt data in form of Strings. I got into a problem. The problem is that I can only encrypt maximum 500 bytes of data with 4096 key size and around 240 bytes with 2048 key size. Also I use `Scanner` and `PrintWriter` for reading and sending data. I found there is class `SSL` but I am not really sure if it can replace `Socket`. I tried sending large data by breaking it into pieces and then sending it but I don't really think it is really efficient. Please can anyone guide me how to make encrypted communication in server.

I want to find a way to encrypt my communication in server.

Comment: RSA is only intended and suitable to encrypt small amount of data, like the keys for symmetric encryption like AES. It is therefore used as part of [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). Given that you are using Socket it looks like you want to protect communication. In this case use the established and widely used TLS as provided by SSLSocket instead of inventing your own.

Comment: So, can I replace `Socket` with `SSLSocket` and communication will be protected?

Comment: Can I transfer large data with SSLSocket?

Comment: *"Can I transfer large data with SSLSocket? "* - Yes, there is no limit. *"can I replace Socket with SSLSocket and communication will be protected?"* - basically yes, but SSLSocket needs additional setup like a certificate on the server side in order to properly protect the communication. There are zillions of examples out there to help you.

Comment: For the record, the reason that RSA is limited to small chunks of data is that encoding and decoding is relatively expensive.  Block ciphers with symmetric keys are orders of magnitude cheaper.  (I couldn't quickly an actual comparison.  Benchmarking studies typically *don't even bother measuring* the performance of public key algorithms.)